# index beyond bounds for empty array when using insertRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Initially, no. Of Section=0 and no. of Rows in a Section=0. When data is available, no. of Section Changes to 1 and no. Rows in a Section keep on incrementing by 1.

```
NSArray *indexPathArray=[NSArray arrayWithObject:rowSectionIndexPath];  
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
[tableView endUpdates];
```

I tried to use the above code, to insert rows in the table. But received the error
**-[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array.**

The row and section value from which i started insertingData into the rows, was
   row=1 and section=1;
   row=2 and section=1;....and so on.

What am i missing in the code, considering the fact that i have used all the required methods numberOfSectionsInTableView , numberOfRowsInSection , cellForRowAtIndexPath and heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help you.

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
            return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {


      return [displayWineList count];//pass your array count
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..,

```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView  
     {            
       return 1;    
     } 

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
      numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section   
     {         
       return [yourArray count];
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The row and section value from which i started insertingData into the rows, was row=1 and section=1; row=2 and section=1;....and so on.

Have you try starting from row = 0? (Maybe you did, but I'm not an english person and the first part of your question is confusing me)

Because if you start with an empty table you need to fill 0 before trying to fill 1.

Answer (score -1):

please write

```
[tableview reloadData]
```

or

```
[tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```